# Jenkins- Getting stuck on install initial plugin page

Tags: jenkins

[image]I have newly configured Jenkins, after setting up the proxy it asks to install plugins, i selected few plugins and after proceeding to install them some of them failed and the install bar completes for other plugins but the page hangs forever and i am not able to proceed further.

Please suggest !

Comment: which Jenkins version? which plugin updates failed?

Comment: Have done the installation on Linux CentOS using terminal commands, didnt specifically installed a version & Pipeline and GitHubOrg plugins failed and it keeps me hanged on this page.

Comment: Added screenshot for more clarification of the issue. This page keeps on coming everytime i access jenkins through localhost.

Answer (score 5):

restart jenkins using "http://localhost:8080/safeRestart"
It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug report that pretty well fits to the description of your problem: [Jenkins- Getting stuck on install initial plugin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222391/jenkins-getting-stuck-on-install-initial-plugin-page). That bug should have been fixed in June (and Jenkins 2.6).

I had the same problem with Jenkis 2.7.3, though. To get the install running, I first removed the installation and started it again. Then I deselected the plugins which have caused the errors and could successfully finish the "getting started" process.

Once you have Jenkins running in normal mode you should be able to install the skipped plugins (didn't try that, though; don't need them).

Answer (score 2):

A simple Page refresh did NOT help me.

I just restarted webapp service, TOMCAT in my case and then a page refresh allowed me to skip and continue to proceed further.

Try this it may help you.

Comment: `systemctl restart jenkins` and after click on resume when jenkins restarts

Answer (score 1):

1. go to this link - http://localhost:8080/safeRestart
2. go to the Dashboard -> Manage Plugins -> Available tab
3. Select all plugins and start installing
4. Jenkins will work after reboot

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug with Jenkins 2.19.3 on Windows. Resolved by reinstalling Jenkins with full Jenkins directory removal.

Answer (score 0):

Okay let me share my success case of this stupid error.

I was using google chrome and i tried everything, uninstall jenkins complete from the face of my HDD, and reinstalling but non work.

Then i took petty on IE (or on myself for that matter) and i ran the jenkins (localhost:8080) on IE and voila! everything works perfectly.

Hope this help anybody.

Comment: I tried this after the other suggestions failed, and this unfortunately has no effect for me either.

Answer (score 0):

well, I am running Jenkins on my remote machine after all the configuration and installing the required plugins the web client dint respond I tried to start it but with no gain.

After digging deeper all I had to do was to restart the Jenkins service and it picks up from where it left.

The reason might be during the installation of the plugins the server is stopped and the additional files are added so during the downtime the Jenkins becomes unresponsive.

hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo service restart jenkins
```

Then go back to refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and did :
$ systemctl restart jenkins
and re-resumed and later continued and installation completed.
post that setup the first admin user and proceeding next.
Trying "Jenkins 2.277.4" at my local dev box